# How to use && in command line in variable in windows

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, command-line

I have a complex program. It needs to execute a series of commands, and I need to use `&&` to combine them into a single one command, but it will make this command very long and thus very difficult to read and maintain.

Thus I tried to use `set` to combine them, the combined command can print correctly, but it can not execute correctly. Below is a example of it. How can I correct this code so it is syntactically valid?

```
@echo off 
set command=dir
set command=%command% ^^^&^^^& tree

rem this line will print the combined string
echo %command%

rem this line will not execute the combined string
%command%

pause
```

`dir && tree` is just an example that I used as an example. In my program there are many command combined together, such as `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && ...`. I can not run them one by one, I need to use `&&` to only run each if the previous one succeeded.

Comment: Note the differing counts of "watchers" for the 2 tags I have added. Your Q seems perfectly acceptable. Good luck.

Comment: I believe you've run into a syntax issue. What exactly does `dir && tree` mean? It *could* be interpreted as you expect; `dir` and then `tree` or it could be interpreted as "I want a directory listing of objects named `&&` or `tree`" From the prompt, you get the first interpretation, within batch the second. If you use `(dir)` in place of `dir` in your batch, it acts as you expect.

Comment: @Magoo Thanks for your reply, I just make it as an example,actually there are many command combined together,such as `cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && ...`,for such reason,I need to run them together with `&&`

Comment: Just to be clear, to run a sequence of commands one after the other, it would be ```cmd1 & cmd2 & cmd3 & …```. This means run `cmd1`, then run `cmd2`, then run `cmd3`, then run `…`. `&&` has a different meaning, so ```cmd1 && cmd2 && cmd3 && …``` means run `cmd1`, and if that command runs successfully run `cmd2`, and if that command runs successfully run `cmd3`, and if that command runs successfully run `…`. The difference between the use of `&` and `&&` can therefore make a very important difference to your intended goal.

Comment: @Compo Thanks for your reply,but `&&` is what I need and Mark's answer meets my demand!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ugly, but below works.  Quote the string, but remove the quotes to execute it:

```bash
@echo off
set command=dir
set command="%command% && tree"

rem this line will print the combined string (quotes as well)
echo %command%

rem this line will execute the combined string
%command:~1,-1%
```

Sample output:

```
"dir && tree"
 Volume in drive C has no label.
 Volume Serial Number is CE8B-D448

 Directory of C:\x

03/05/2023  10:44 PM    <DIR>          .
03/05/2023  10:44 PM    <DIR>          ..
03/05/2023  10:44 PM    <DIR>          a
03/05/2023  10:44 PM    <DIR>          b
03/05/2023  10:43 PM               204 x.bat
               1 File(s)            204 bytes
               4 Dir(s)  19,423,408,128 bytes free
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is CE8B-D448
C:.
├───a
└───b
```

Comment: Hi Mark,I just tested it and find that if I put more commands like `set command="%command% && xxx"`,it will not work,can you help me,please? Such as `set command=ver
set command="%command% && dir"
set command="%command% && tree"`

Comment: That’s a different issue but similar solution. `set command="%command:~1,-1% && tree"` should work to chain the commands if the variable already has quotes. Start with `set command="ver"` as well

Comment: Thanks,I just tested your solution and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Not using a one-liner is hopefully a much cleaner solution.

```
if dir tree
```

or, in the general case,

```
if cmd1 (if cmd2 (if cmd3 (if cmd4 cmd5))))
```

The parentheses let you easily split the code over multiple lines for improved legibility, too.

Answer (score 1):

`&&` means "if the prior command succeeded"

"Succeeded" is naturally observer-dependent.

So, I'd suggest

```
set "commands="dir""
set "commands=%commands% "tree""
for %%e in (%commands%) do if not errorlevel 1 %%~e
```